# How to add a rectangle behind the title?

Tags: titles

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\title{\textbf{TITLE TITLE} \\ {\Large\itshape Subtitle}} % Title and subtitle

\author{Author} 
\date{February 2021}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{ 
    \vspace*{20pt} % Vertical whitespace before the title
    \begin{flushright} % Right align
        {\LARGE\@title} % Increase the font size of the title
        
        \vspace{30pt} % Vertical whitespace between the title and author name
        
        {\large\@author}\\ % Author name
        \@date % Date
        
        \vspace{20pt} % Vertical whitespace between the author block and abstract
    \end{flushright}
}
\makeatother
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
```

That generates:

[image]

But I like to add a rectangle as the background of the title:[image]

Or even fancier than that. How do I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: The tcolorbox might be useful here. You could use a box such as `\begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners, rounded corners=northwest, rounded corners=southwest, arc=5mm, colback=myorange, colframe=myorange, text width=5cm]`

Comment: @leandriis Thanks. I also add `text height=5cm`. It is rendered but is placed on the left side and not right side of the paper, how do I fix it?

Comment: If you place the `tcolorbox` inside of  the `flushright` environment, you should get a right-aligned title with the expected background.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the `tcolorbox` package you can achieve a similar output. Depending on the actual title and subtitle of your document, you might have to adjust the value of `text width`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\title{\textbf{TITLE TITLE} \\ {\Large\itshape Subtitle}} % Title and subtitle

\author{Author} 
\date{February 2021}

\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{244,177,130}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \vspace*{20pt} % Vertical whitespace before the title
    \begin{flushright} % Right align 
      \begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners,
                        rounded corners=northwest, 
                        rounded corners=southwest,
                        arc=5mm,
                        colback=myorange,
                        colframe=myorange,
                        text width=5cm]
        {\LARGE\@title} % Increase the font size of the title
       
        \vspace{30pt} % Vertical whitespace between the title and author name
        
        {\large\@author} % Author name
        
        \@date % Date
        
        \vspace{20pt} % Vertical whitespace between the author block and abstract

        \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{flushright}
}
\makeatother
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

---

With the help of `adjustbox` from the `changepage` package, the orange box can be stretched into the margin:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{changepage}

\title{\textbf{TITLE TITLE} \\ {\Large\itshape Subtitle}} % Title and subtitle
\author{Author} 
\date{February 2021}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{244,177,130}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \vspace*{20pt}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-1in}
      \begin{flushright}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[sharp corners,
                        rounded corners=northwest, 
                        rounded corners=southwest,
                        arc=5mm,
                        colback=myorange,
                        colframe=myorange,
                        text width=\dimexpr4cm+1in]
          {\LARGE\@title}
       
          \vspace{30pt}
        
          {\large\@author}
        
          \@date
        
          \vspace{20pt}
        \end{tcolorbox}
      \end{flushright}
    \end{adjustwidth}
}
\makeatother
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Due to the 1inch margin of the page, the orange box does not cover the margin area on the right side of the box, is there any way to cover that particular area as well?

Comment: @Coder: I have just updated my answer to include a different version in which the orange box also spans the whole right margin up to the page border. I hope this suits your needs.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.